# How to enter two activity links in another activity?

Tags: java, android, button, hyperlink

I know my question might be stupid but I am new in Android App development and the Eclipse things but reached to e problem that can't find solution in internet.
I am making multi-activity application and reached to a point where when i have two buttons in one of the activities and want each of them to lead to different other activities, the application crashes. When I lead them both to one activity, everything is fine. Here is my code and hope really my question not to be so stupid as I am thinking.

```
public class Home extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tables);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(goToTables);
        Button mySecondButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reservations);
        mySecondButton.setOnClickListener(goToMenu);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private OnClickListener goToTables = new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            doButton();
        }};     
        private void doButton()
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Tables.class));
        }

    private OnClickListener goToMenu = new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            doSecondButton();
        }}; 
        private void doSecondButton()
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Menu.class));
        } 
}
```

The `goToTables` works perfectly but I am missing something important to change in `goToMenu`. My other activities are: ***Tables*** and ***Menu***. Can somebody please tell me where I am wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since crashes will occur all the time in code development the best use of your time now is to learn about logcat and post a stacktrace. The stacktrace will make the crash very easy to diagnose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the name of your Menu activity or add the full name path of Menu.class in your intent, eg. `com.myapp.Menu.class`

Comment: The problem was quite stupid as I expected... the `public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` was duplicating `(Menu menu)` with the name of my other class - **Menu**.class and the android can't find my class because of that so when i changed the name of the class it started working perfectly.

Comment: That was what I suspected.

Answer (score 1):

android:onClick="dobutton" try adding this in your button tag in xml code rather then using onclicklistner.

Comment: this means that your intent is passed on to menu activity.But your menu activity is getting freezed causing your app to stop working.

Comment: Log.v(TAG, "in oncreate of menu activity"); add this in menuactivity oncreate method and then check your console.that is how you can see where your code gets dysfunctional